# Confusion about the term current density

Tags: electromagnetism

I was reading Purcell's Electricity and Magnetism . In the following picture(eq:4.3) summation of all current flow has been taken for k groups of particles. I am not explaining all the things here but those who have reed the whole text know that in the time interval ∆t all the classes of particles don't overcome that frame together. So for all classes of particles ∆t must need to be different and thus there shouldn't be any shortened summation form as shown in the picture. What's your comment?
[image]

For further clarification I added the following picture which describes my thought. [image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

"in the time interval ∆t all the classes of particles don't overcome that frame together."

We are counting particles going through an area, as if we were counting dogs jumping through a hoop. We have divided the dogs into classes with different numbers of collars (different charges), different velocities of approach and different numbers per cubic metre.

The dogs don't have to go through the hoop at once. Over a time interval $\Delta t$, dogs with the greatest velocity component normal to the hoop, with most collars and with most dogs per m$^3$ will carry most collars through the hoop. Dogs with the least velocity component normal to the hoop, least number of  collars, and most spread out (fewest per m$^3$) will carry fewest collars through the hoop.

Comment: see at my second picture there at the last line ∆t_k and ∆t aren't same thus can't be cancelled out. Only if ∆t→0 then ∆t_k also tends to zero and both can be cancelled out. Otherwise ∆t_k remains and vary from 0<∆t_k<∆t . That's my thought.

Comment: Δ is the same for all groups, but the lengths of your imaginary oblique prisms are different for groups with different velocities. The prisms are longer for faster dogs (or charged particles!) because in the same time, Δ, faster dogs will be able to come from further away from the hoop, but still get through it in the same time. Remember: the prism for that velocity of dog (particle) contains all the dogs of that velocity that will pass through the hoop in time  Δ.

Comment: @The Photon I don't agree. The prism contains all the dogs that will pass through the hoop in time $\Delta t$. So the dog at the end of the prism furthest from the hoop at the beginning of $\Delta t$ must get through the hoop in that time. We must have some sort of misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

The source text defines $n_k$ as the average population density of the $k$th class of particles per cubic meter.

That is, it assumes we can assume that the particles are distributed evenly enough and are passing through the frame in sufficient numbers that we can treat them as being spread out in space rather than localized. And that the number of particles (of each class) passing through the frame can be treated as a continuous value rather than quantized.

If the particles carrying the charge are treated as spread out in space, and their number is continuous rather than quantized, then the charge itself must also be spread out in space, and its value may also be treated as continuous rather than quantized.

In that approximation, then, we can treat the charge as passing through the frame in a continuous stream, rather than in quantized lumps. And so we can define the current density at a point within the frame.

Answer (score 0):

This is something of a strange question.  Purcell in my reading clearly intends it to be the *same* unit of time for each particle species.

My best guess about what you mean is that you want to track different units of time for different densities to see a single particle go through the area, or so? That is a natural understanding of current but requires a different argument than Purcell makes.

## The average distance to the next particle argument

Suppose you have $N$ particles in a box of volume $V$, all at rest. So they have a number density $n=N/V$. We want to ask a question like, “given that I draw some imaginary plane through a particle, how far (on average) is the next particle from this plane?” . Then when these things are moving, we can use this distance to figure out the time it takes for the next particle to pass through Purcell’s frame, but first we need to know the average distance, before we set anything into motion!

Well, take our planes parallel to one side of the box with area $A$, and draw a separate plane for each particle: we are asking about the spacing of these planes on average. But I can just answer that! There are $N$ planes set out over a distance $L=V/A$, the average spacing is $L/N = 1/(n~A).$ So this result says if I double the size of the cross-sectional area that particles are passing through, but keep the density constant, then the distance to the next particle halves: the distance goes inversely as the area.

(You can kind of see this if you imagine a certain homogeneity too, imagine two areas side-by-side with a very regular current flow through them, so that the particles traveling through each pass through like the ticking of a clock. The clocks tick at the same rate, just not in sync... Then the average time between ticks considering both clocks together has to be half the time between each one separately, as there is exactly one tick of clock B between every tick of clock A and vice versa.)

Once we have this result we can think about Purcell’s problem, setting the charges in motion and seeing how many pass through a frame. Right after a charge passes through the frame, we know the average distance to the next particle is $1/(n~a)$ where $a$ is the area of the frame. Now the particle is moving with velocity $v$ but obviously only the component of velocity perpendicular to the area draws it closer to the frame, so the perpendicular velocity is $v\cos\theta$ and the average time to the next particle is
$$
\Delta t_k =\frac{1}{n_k~a~v_k\cos\theta_k}.
$$
The current counts charges per unit time $$I_k =\frac{q_k}{\Delta t_k} = q_k n_k \mathbf a\cdot\mathbf v_k.$$
Now there is no problem with summing-up all of the different time intervals, so for example if you introduce a common time $\Delta t$ then the total charge that passes through due to each group is $Q_k=q_k \Delta t/\Delta t_k$ and if we just sum all charges, $Q=\sum_k Q_k = \Delta t\sum_k I_k.$ Purcell is correct to point out that the sum of the partial currents is the total current.

## Why didn't Purcell have to do all of this?

Purcell’s argument was instead that the area $\mathbf a$ can be translated back in time a common time $\Delta t$ for all particles, along different velocity vectors $\mathbf v_k$. When you do this the same time and area sweeps out some different volumes $\Delta V_k = \mathbf a\cdot\mathbf v_k~\Delta t$. The key is, any particle of population $k$ that happened to be in that volume during that time, would have gone through the surface by the end of it. So we have a density and we have a volume and we multiply that to get a count, $\Delta N_k = n_k~\Delta V_k$ and a count of particles
times a charge per particle give us an overall charge, $\Delta Q_k = q_k ~\Delta N_k,$ and the sum over all of the different populations $k$ gives the total charge that passed through that surface in that time, $I =\Delta Q/\Delta t.$ It is a much faster way to the same conclusion, but it requires this counterintuitive step of translating an area backwards in time along some vector, and Purcell is trying to make that more intuitive for his readers.